# How to subscribe to Movies and TV weekly newsletter?

Tags: support, status-completed

I'm pretty much interested with Movies and TV Stack Exchange site.Unfortunately, I can't visit the movies and tv site quite often.Surprisingly i couldn't find any link in movies and tv to subscribe to newsletter.So,**How to subscribe to Movies and TV weekly newsletter to get the top question** like the one in **stackoverflow**.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, in the side space of the sites you will see a way to do it.  Not sure if this is true of beta sites as I cannot see it myself, even after disabling ad-block

If you do not see this link, you can always go to the [**SE Network Newsletter site**](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) and search for movies in the top bar and click *subscribe*

Comment: +1 for your immediate assistance:)